# C# Container Question

Tags: c#, insert, loops, containers, exit

I'm having a weird problem with adding stuff to my Container. Whenever I try to add the items it simply exits the while loop, even though isServer is still 1. I've tried to make a custom function, same result. Then i tried calling the Add(..) function directly and still same result. I don't see how inserting items to my container is supposed to exit the loop? Here's the gamedata class:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that you could be getting an Exception? Some of the higher-up code may be catching and tossing the exception. Try wrapping the HandleSListPacket method in a Try/Catch block, and use a custom dialog to display the Exception.

```
try {
   // HandleSListPacket() code goes here
}
catch (Exception ex) {
   MessageBox.Show("Caught Exception: " + ex);
   throw;
}
```

Comment: Totally forgot about that! Thank you, it threw this exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback on Spodi's answer, is it possible that you're adding duplicate keys to the `ServerList`? This is not permitted with the `Dictionary` type, so if 2 identical `realServerName` values are added an exception would be thrown.

Comment: I have found the mistake, I haven't initialized the gamedata class properly, duh! Thanks for your help!